# iOS App - Display images in a grid view froma list of JSON URL.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json, uiimageview

I'm storing a list of URLs in a MYSQL db table and I have been able to successfully retrieve the URLS via JSON.

However, now that I have the JSON I am not sure how to display the images in a image gallery type view in my iPhone App.

What I plan on having is a huge list of URL's to image in the database and I want to display x amount at a time and then once the user scrolls to the end I want to display x amount more. Like pinterest.

Any hints?

```
#import "mySQLAppViewController.h"


@interface mySQLAppViewController (){

}

- (IBAction)loadJSON:(id)sender;

@end


@implementation mySQLAppViewController

- (IBAction)loadJSON:(id)sender {

    NSString *dataUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://MYDOMAIN.com/results.php"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:dataUrl];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
    [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
            success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

               for (int i =0 ; i < [JSON count]; i++) {

                   //NSString *image_url = JSON[i][@"image_url"];
                   //NSLog(@"%@", image_url);
                   //^^THIS SUCESSFULLY LOGS THE URL LINKS (I.E. HTTP://MYDOMAIN.COM/CAR.JPG)

                   NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:JSON[i][@"image_url"]];
                   NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
                   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];


               }

            }

            failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                             message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error]
                                                            delegate:nil
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [av show];
            }];

    [operation start];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to look at UICollectionView. Here's a tutorial to get you started: 
[Beginning UICollectionView In iOS 6](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12).

Comment: Link provided is broke right now, but here is the Apple ref until it is back up: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html

+1 Upvote for suggesting this... I was assuming iOS 5 for some reason, but that would be perfect for this if @Alex can do iOS 6 as a minimum. With iOS 7 around the corner, I don't see why he couldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Edited after davidm's answer to be more complete: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16918758/412339) Mark his as answer if it (UICollectionView) is the best for your solution.

iOS 6 and above:

You should really check out UICollectionView. A really good resource for this is found here: [Create an iOS 6 UICollectionView Using Storyboards](http://maniacdev.com/2012/09/tutorial-how-to-create-an-ios-6-uicollectionview-using-storyboards)

iOS 5 and lower:

One thing that you can do is create a custom ViewController that has an array of your image URLs or your JSON Array:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *imageURLs;
```

Then create a set of reusable UIImageViews (which is another question in itself, but basically you need an array that holds custom UIImageViews with a reuse identifier, similar to a UITableViewCell).

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *imageViews;
```

Finally, you will need a UIScrollView and UIView (to contain the UIImageViews) that watches the position and adds the imageview on the screen using a [UIScrollViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate.html) method (scrollViewDidScroll: should work).

Alternatively, you can just implement a UITableViewController and Delegate with a custom UITableViewCell and let Apple's engineers take care of most of that for you, but you won't be able to put photos side by side, only stacked on top of each other. That may be what you are wanting though.